# How to reduce the memory utilization by lsof.log?

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, logs

`lsof.log` is consuming lot of space. The log file size has increased up to 7 GB.

How do I optimize the space utilization by `lsof.log` file. Should I delete it on regular basis or is there a way around.

Answer (score 0):

Log rotation is the solution of increasing log file size.

Use `logrotate` command.